# Integrate psake with MsBuild

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, psake

I am using MSBuild for CI. I was looking recently to psake as an additional tool for creating scripts for daily builds as I need to do some updates to our builds which will be easier in psake. For the moment I’m not looking to replace our existing scripts as it requires a lot of work but keep the existing ones and add new using psake.

My question is - when I create a build in TFS how can I run the psake scripts after the solution is built? My understanding is that I need to add a new target after the build is executed and execute the psake/powershell. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is how you would do it. It is best to separate different parts of your build script so that if you want to change something, you can proceed with ease.

So, Ideally, you should have a task for compiling your solution, another for running the tests, another for packaging the source and so on ... I recently started using psake, and [this](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake/wiki) is a good reference in case you want to look up something.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to use TeamCity to run your psake build scripts. In your psake scripts you would create a psake Task that calls msbuild via `exec { msbuild yourSolution.sln }`.